# Encrypting secrets in config maps

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any way to encrypt secrets in configmaps for kubernetes deployments? I'm using flux so I need all of my deployment files to be stored in git, I encrypt all the secrets' manifests using kubeseal but I haven't found a good solution for protecting secrets in configmaps (usually config files contain stuff like username/password).

Comment: ConfigMaps really don't have a build in mechanism as they are not meant to store secrets.

Comment: @Blokje5 I know but numerous well know applications still work this way (read credentials from config files), for example this is what I'm talking about in my specific use case https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/v3.2.0.2/simple/kubernetes-apim/wso2apim-conf.yaml and it's just one example out of many.

Comment: Yes true, then it is often hoping that the config files support e.g. environment variable interpolation. You could always use an init container that uses e.g. `sed` to replace values in the file with environment variables.

Comment: That would work I guess but it's a hassle and wouldn't scale well as a solution, I was hoping for a cleaner more convenient solution.. Why no one thought of a tool like kubeseal that would read a manifest, replace variables in it with given secrets and create the config map out of it? I was hoping for something like that at least.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way to reference secrets in k8s.
You can use the workaround offered [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/79224#issuecomment-618009379) to load a secret as an environment variable and reference it in your configmap, but keep in mind loading secrets as environment variable is not recommended.

Comment: I'm talking about the use case where an app doesn't support referencing env variables in the config file actually.

Comment: You might still be able to leverage that using yaml variables - https://anil.io/blog/symfony/yaml/using-variables-in-yaml-files/, pull the env var into the yaml and then inject it as part of the config.

Comment: Really not sure how that would help actually since this is just a direct referencing feature, basically just to avoid repeating blocks within the same yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

> Caution: ConfigMap does not provide secrecy or encryption. If the data you want to store are confidential, use a Secret rather than a ConfigMap, or use additional (third party) tools to keep your data private.

From: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/